# How do I iterate over each element in an HTML list when testing with WebdriverIO and Mocha + Chai?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I am trying to assert that each item in a certain `<ol>` element exists. The closest solution I can find on SO and elsewhere is to use `.elements`, yet this still does not work. The length of the `<ol>` element varies on different pages, so it cannot be hardcoded into the test. See my current test below, which should fail at `i.should.not.exist` but passes.

```
it('category hierarchy navigation test',function() {

      return client
          .url(Page.url)
          .then(function() {
            ItemPage.categoryHierarchy.should.exist;
          })
          .then(function() {
            return client.elements(ItemPage.categoryHierarchy, function(err, res){
              for (let i in res.value) {
                i.should.not.exist;
              }
            })
          })
    })
```

What is the proper way of getting an array of and iterating over the `<li>` elements inside an `<ol>`?

Comment: what happens if you do `var parent = browser.element('Selectorol');console.log(parent.elements('Selectorli').value)` , it should log array and then you can iterate over it.

Comment: I can't see the logs in my terminal because Selenium is running Firefox. I previously assumed the logs would appear the Firefox window it is running, but this does not seem to be the case.

Earlier research on the issue was not fruitful--unless someone can help me find these logs, I need a way other than relying on console logging here.

Comment: `console.log` just print on the terminal from which you are running the script. Or you can use `browser.log(type);` , look [here](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/log.html) for documentation